# Forall quantifier and complex boolean propositions in Idris

Tags: logic, prefix, dependent-type, idris

I'm new to dependent types and, having a Haskell experience, am slowly learning Idris. For an exercize, I want to write a Huffman encoding. Currently I'm trying to write a proof that the "flattening" of the code tree produces a prefix code, but has got stuck with the quantifiers.

I have a simple inductive proposition that one list is a prefix of an another:

```
using (xs : List a, ys : List a)
    data Prefix : List a -> List a -> Type where
        pEmpty : Prefix Nil ys
        pNext  : (x : a) -> Prefix xs ys -> Prefix (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
```

1. Is this a valid approach? Or something like "*xs* is prefix of *ys* if there is *zs* such that *xs* ++ *zs* = *ys*" would be better?
2. Was it the right way to introduce a "forall" quantifier (as far as I can understand, in Agda it would be something like `pNext : ∀ {x xs ys} → Prefix xs ys → Prefix (x :: xs) (y :: ys)`)? Should the pNext first argument be implicit? What is the semantic differences between two variants?

Then, I want to build one for a vector where none of elements forms a prefix of another:

```
data PrefVect : Vect n (List a) -> Type where
```

Empty vector has no prefixes:

```
    pvEmpty : PrefVect Nil
```

and given an element x, a vector xs, and proofs that none element of xs is a prefix of x (and vice versa), x :: xs will hold that property:

```
    pvNext  : (x : [a]) -> (xs : Vect n [a]) ->
              All (\y => Not (Prefix x y)) xs ->
              All (\y => Not (Prefix y x)) xs ->
              PrefVect (x :: xs)
```

This is an unvalid type which I hope to fix after dealing with the first one, but there is similar question about quantifiers in pvNext: is this variant acceptable, or there is a better way to form a "negation on relation"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only problem here is that you've used `[a]` as the type of lists of `a`, in the Haskell style, whereas in Idris it needs to be `List a`.

Your `Prefix` type looks fine to me, although I'd write it as:

```
data Prefix : List a -> List a -> Type where
     pEmpty : Prefix [] ys
     pNext : Prefix xs ys -> Prefix (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
```

That is, `x` can be implicit, and you don't need the `using` because Idris can infer the types of `xs` and `ys`. Whether this is the right approach or not really depends on what you plan to use the `Prefix` type for. It's certainly easy enough to test whether a list is the prefix of another. Something like:

```
testPrefix : DecEq a => (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) -> Maybe (Prefix xs ys)
testPrefix [] ys = Just pEmpty
testPrefix (x :: xs) [] = Nothing
testPrefix (x :: xs) (y :: ys) with (decEq x y)
  testPrefix (x :: xs) (x :: ys) | (Yes Refl) = Just (pNext !(testPrefix xs ys
  testPrefix (x :: xs) (y :: ys) | (No contra) = Nothing
```

If you want to prove the negation, which it seems you might, you'll need the type to be:

```
testPrefix : DecEq a => (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) -> Dec (Prefix xs ys)
```

I'll leave that one as an exercise :).